# Wordpress theme crashed, and wp-admin not working - php issue

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, admin

I created a wordpress website for a cleaning company, and now they got back to me that something is wrong with their website. When I try to open it I get error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in
>   /home3/feelthespiri/public_html/pgscleaning.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/meta-box/inc/sanitizer.php
>   on line 60
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in
>   /home3/feelthespiri/public_html/pgscleaning.co.uk/wp-content/mu-plugins/endurance-page-cache.php on line 370

When I try to get to the admin panel I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in
>   /home3/feelthespiri/public_html/pgscleaning.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/meta-box/inc/sanitizer.php
>   on line 60

and this is line 60-63 in the php file:

```
public function switch( $value ) {  
  return (int) ! empty( $value );

} 

}
```

Can anyone guide me, how to proceed cus I'm really lost, thanks.

Comment: have you tried deactivating those plugins?

Comment: switch is default php function. you cannot use as custom function

Comment: back this plugin `mu-plugins` up somewhere, ftp into your server and remove this `mu-plugins` plugin this way: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/ - and see if it is working

Comment: I couldn't deactivate the plugin the way it was described in the article : / I tried to delete the entire folders of the plugins but nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

Go to this folder /home3/feelthespiri/public_html/pgscleaning.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/meta-box/ and rename meta-box and acces your admin dashboard by pgscleaning.co.uk/wp-admin

Comment: Tried to rename it to meta-box-disabled, tried to delete it, and yet it keeps showing the same error, any other suggestions? :/